# List into a formatted string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a very simple problem but can't seem to figure it out. I've created a list of strings. But i want to format the list into a string that looks like an array.

So for example this is my list

```
List<string> testData = new List<string> ();
testData.Add("test 1");
testData.Add("test 2");
```

I want to then format all the data into a string hopefully to look like this:

```
['test 1', 'test 2']
```

Ive tried to use a string.Join but that doesnt get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Do the quotes have to be single quotes?  If not, you could look in to JSON.NET.

Comment: I would go with a custom class that inherits the `List<T>` and then override the  ToString method

Comment: Yes single quotes

Comment: Or a custom extention method that will create the string you need

Comment: I'd advise to properly escape special characters, or use regular JSON encoding, unless you're 100% sure nobody is ever going to use the code in the future and enter any special character! Always build your code future-proof and fail-proof. The proposed solutions don't handle that. If you don't escape properly, and someone is able to influence the input of your function, he'd be able to corrupt your data with data injection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Ive tried to use a string.Join but that doesn't get the results I'm looking for.

That's true. However, string format can help:

```
var res = "[" + string.Join(", ", testData.Select(s => $"'{s}'")) + "]";
```

Prior to C# 6, you would need to use `string.Format` explicitly:

```
var res = "[" + string.Join(", ", testData.Select(s => string.Format("'{0}'", s))) + "]";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = "[" + String.Join(", ", testData.Select(c => "'" + c + "'")) + "]";
```

Comment: you forgot to close the outer parentheses

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = "[" + string.Join(",", testData.Select(i => "'" + i + "'").ToArray()) + "]";
```

Comment: It is not necessary to add .ToArray() anymore. It works without ToArray() extension.

Comment: That's weird, i'm gettting: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: With .NET Frameork 4.0, Join accepts IEnumerable as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = $"['{String.Join("', '", testData)}']";
```

or

```
var result = "['" + string.Join("', '", testData) + "']";
```